# Overwrite input variable in R function

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a pattern in a string and then replace that pattern with a new one.

```
fullstring <- paste(sample(c('a','t','c','g'),1000,replace=T),collapse='')

replacestrfunction <- function(searchstr,fullstring,replacestr) {
  nummatches <- lengths(regmatches(fullstring, gregexpr(searchstr, fullstring, fixed = TRUE)))
  regmatches(fullstring, gregexpr(searchstr, fullstring, fixed = TRUE))<-replacestr
  return(cat('There are',nummatches,'occurences of',searchstr,'in the string','\n',
             'These were replaced with',replacestr,'\n'))
}
```

I'm having issues with replacing the 'outside' variable of fullstring with the new string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is `dna` in your function. You have got the 1st part correct to count number of occurrences of the string. To replace that pattern with the new one use `gsub` :

```
replacestrfunction <- function(searchstr,fullstring,replacestr) {
  nummatches <- lengths(regmatches(fullstring, gregexpr(searchstr, 
                        fullstring, fixed = TRUE)))
  fullstring <- gsub(searchstr, replacestr, fullstring, fixed = TRUE)
  cat('There are',nummatches,'occurences of',searchstr,'in the string','\n',
             'These were replaced with',replacestr,'\n')
  return(fullstring)
}
replacestrfunction('atc', fullstring, 'z')
```

Comment: thank you that worked. dna was an old variable name that I forgot to replace. It should have also been fullstring.